# Datetime Picker value won't update in database on post

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datetimepicker

Trying to use the jquery datetimepicker and I can get the addon to work, however, when I post the data it doesn't update in the database. Everything else updates, but the date/time.

Note: I realize some of this is still mysql, I'm working to update the entire site.

edit_release_form.php, I have

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://vmcnucmed.cvm.umn.edu/includes/js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://vmcnucmed.cvm.umn.edu/includes/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script>
  $( function() {
    $('#datetime_released').datetimepicker({
    controlType: 'select',
    oneLine: true,
    timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss tt'
});
  } );
  </script>
```

My input:

```
 <input tabindex="1" id="datetime_released" type="text" name="datetime_released" >
```

post.php

```
<?php
// Database Conection Parameters
define('DB_SERVER', "hostname");
define('DB_USER', "username");
define('DB_PASSWORD', "password");
define('DB_TABLE', "database");

// Connection to the Database
$mysqli = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_TABLE);
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
$mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

if (mysqli_connect_errno($mysqli)) {
    trigger_error('Database connection failed: '  . mysqli_connect_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
}

$datetime_released = $_POST['datetime_released']; 
$release_probeSN = $_POST['release_probeSN']; 
$release_reading = $_POST['release_reading'];
$release_reading_loc = $_POST['release_reading_loc'];
$releasedby = $_POST['releasedby'];
$id = $_POST['id'];


// Query
$sql = "
UPDATE xxx
SET datetime_released=?, 
release_probeSN=?, 
release_reading=?, 
release_reading_loc=?,
releasedby=?

WHERE patientdoseID=?";
if(!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)))
{
  die("Unable to prepare statement");
}
else
{
  $stmt->bind_param("sissii", $datetime_released, $release_probeSN, $release_reading, $release_reading_loc, $releasedby, $id);    
  if($stmt->execute())
  {
    echo 'Patient Updated Successfully. <br /><br />Database ID: <br>';
          header('Location: http://vmcnucmed.cvm.umn.edu', 
            TRUE, // rewrite existing Location header
            302 // set status code
);
  }
  else
  {
    die("Update failed");
  }
}

mysqli_close($mysqli);

?>
```

Comment: You need to provide more detail as we don' know what the value of $datetime_released is after you submitted it.  Have you tried to print out the _POST data to make sure it has a value? It might be that $_POST is empty and there's nothing wrong with the database.

Comment: SQL flavours are very picky in the date(time) formats they accept. (Culture can also affect the result!).
For example try to store as text (for debugging purposes) to see if values are submitted. If so, write a date-time converter to assure value is stored in accepted format.

Comment: @AdamWhateverson - The date/time prints out as 08/25/2016 05:19:20 am 
Pieter21 - I added a new field in database that was just text, posted the value to that field without problems. Now I will need to figure out how to write a date-time converter ...

Comment: got it. I added : $date = date('Y-m-d G:i:s', strtotime($_POST['datetime_released']));      and it posted perfectly. thanks for the help/suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can convert a posted js date into mysql format.
The PHP DateTime object can accept various formats and usually converts them correctly.
You could easily package this into a function - for readability.

```
<?php
// set your timezone somewhere prior to creating a DateTime object
// to prevent local vs UTC issues
date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');

// mysql date format
$format = "Y-m-d H:i:s";

// an example input
$input = '08/25/2016 05:19:20 am';

// convert input date into a PHP DateTime object
$my_date = new DateTime($input);

// create a string in the desired mysql format
$output = $my_date->format($format);

echo $output;

// outputs  2016-08-25 05:19:20  - just the way mysql likes it
```